# Shared memory and cache Ehcache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openshift, ehcache

With the risk of asking an obvious question:

If I were to set up two pods running a spring boot application with shared memory (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.10/html/developer_guide/dev-guide-shared-memory) and use Ehcache for caching requests to a database. Would I need to set up a distributed cache with e.g. Terracotta/Move to another caching manager such as Redis? Or would the cache also be shared between these two pods with the shared memory?

How does the shared memory affect the cache of the two pods?

Comment: EHCache will always use a MemoryStore, so cached objects will be stored on the Heap, which will be your shared memory.  Even if you use BigMemory or DiskStore, the MemoryStore will still be used.  You should note, though, that two pods running in shared memory will not share the same EHCache; you will have two caches in memory; for this reason, you'll want to use a distributed cache.